# Java Selenium open TOR browser

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, tor, firefox-profile

I try to open the Tor browser by Java + Selenium + CheckoDriver + Tor browser.  The code below open the Tor browser but with the "Tor failed to start" error. Maybe someone  faced with this problem or have some another solution to solve problem (only on the Java) thanks !

```
 public static void test3() {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\tor\\geckodriver.exe");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\tor\\geckodriver.exe");

                FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\tor\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default"));
                torProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
                torProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
                torProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
                options.setBinary("C:\\tor\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe");
                options.setProfile(torProfile);
                options.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options);

                FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
            }
```

I think, maybe it is problem with setPreference ( proxy.. )

Answer (score 1):

To open the TOR browser by using Selenium, GheckoDriver and Java, you need to start the [tor](/questions/tagged/tor) daemon first through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and you can use the following solution:

```
package demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class A_Tor_Firefox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/Debanjan.B/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\Debanjan.B\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe");
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\Debanjan.B\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default"));
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", "False");
    options.setProfile(profile);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://check.torproject.org");

    }
}
```

Comment: Used your example, but the Firefox browser is opened

Comment: Code example - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DcdquNSy6evyA_J5KZskKLdrFYkHXvCyrj1GSiBNNcI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @тарас дідик Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: got the same result. The "Tor failed to start" error is displayed